# Gstreamer RTSP to HLS streaming on Windows

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp, http-live-streaming

I am having trouble using Gstreamer's `gst-launch` command line tool for creating HLS playlist from RTSP live stream. The command I have -

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e rtspsrc protocols=tcp location=rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.15:554/Streaming/channels/202  ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse config-interval=-1 ! hlssink location="D:\\wamp\\www\\stream\\%06d.ts" playlist-location="D:\\wamp\\www\\stream\\play.m3u8" target-duration=5
```

creates the .ts files and the playlsit file but I am unable to play it in VLC or FFMPEG's ffplay. While googling this I noticed that most commands to accomplish the same thing have the `mpegtsmux` plugin specified but when I include it in my command I get `WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "mpegtsmux"`. Does Windows  Gstreamer's binaries not include this plugin? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Check your installation. The installer has different install options. Perhaps select "Full install".

Comment: That was exactly the problem, I forgot to post the answer here, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to choose the 'Complete' installation option during GStreamer's installation procedure to get all the required plugins.